# Float Left using Flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using Flex for displaying checkboxes. I am able to achieve the requirements for the large and small resolutions but for the medium resolution, the checkboxes doesn't seem to be working as expected. Just trying to make all the boxes to float left.

Source code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Row className="py-3">
      <Col className="col-3 mx-1">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <b>FIFA 2022 QUALIFIERS</b>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Col>

      <Col className="col-2">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;All&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <Input type="checkbox" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Row className="d-flex">
          <Flex>
            <Input type="checkbox" />
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;ARG</span>
          </Flex>
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Flex.tsx file, add `flex-grow-0` class. For more information check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
  <Col className="d-flex gap-1 flex-grow-0" {...props}>
    {children}
  </Col>
```

Btw, in the screenshot you provided, FRA and SOU are slightly misaligned for medium resolution. If you also want to fix that, give width to the `Col` element in the Flex component.